No Print is coming from customScrollPhysics Flutter
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Custom Scroll Physics Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ScrollPhysicsDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class ScrollPhysicsDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Custom Scroll Physics Example'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        physics: CustomScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('Item $index'),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  // You can adjust these values as per your requirements
  final double itemHeight = 50.0;

  CustomScrollPhysics({ScrollPhysics? parent}) : super(parent: parent);

  @override
  Simulation? createBallisticSimulation(
      ScrollMetrics position, double velocity) {
    final from = position.pixels;
    final ScrollMetrics metrics = position.copyWith();
    final target = _getTargetPixels(metrics, velocity);
    if (from == target) {
      return null;
    }
    return ScrollSpringSimulation(spring, from, target, velocity,
        tolerance: toleranceFor(metrics));
  }

  double _getTargetPixels(ScrollMetrics metrics, double velocity) {

    double page = metrics.pixels / itemHeight;
    print("BPSTB page,$page");
    if (velocity < -tolerance.velocity) {
      page -= 0.5;
    } else if (velocity > tolerance.velocity) {
      page += 0.5;
    } else {
      if (velocity < 0) {
        page -= 0.5;
      } else if (velocity > 0) {
        page += 0.5;
      } else {
        page = (metrics.pixels + itemHeight / 2) / itemHeight;
      }
    }

    return _getPage(page.roundToDouble()) * itemHeight;
  }

  double _getPage(double page) {
    print("BPSTB cmlamp");
    return page.clamp(0.0, double.infinity);
  }

  @override
  bool get allowImplicitScrolling => false;
}

I m trying to print above in customScrollPhysics, while trying to swipe up or down. Shouldn't those print line get executed and printed on debug console?
How do i make sure print from inside customScrollPhysics is working?
PS: I dont have any more details to add just copy pasting this line to satisvy stackoverflow requirnment for more details.
PS: I dont have any more details to add just copy pasting this line to satisvy stackoverflow requirnment for more details.
PS: I dont have any more details to add just copy pasting this line to satisvy stackoverflow requirnment for more details.
PS: I dont have any more details to add just copy pasting this line to satisvy stackoverflow requirnment for more details.

read the official docs of ScrollPhysics.applyTo  method
